# How can I find the number of solutions of equations like this one $x^{11}+12x^{7}+2x^{2}+10 \equiv 0 \text{ (mod 15)}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there a way to find the number of solutions of equations in this form  $$x^{11}+12x^{7}+2x^{2}+10 \equiv 0 \text{ (mod 15)}$$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ or more general $\text{(mod n)}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$?

I know that I can write the equation as a set of equations $$\text{ (mod 3)}$$ and $$\text{ (mod 5)}$$ or in general the solutions are given using the Chinese reminder theorem solving the set of equations $$\text{ (mod pq...v)}$$ where p and q are prime factors of n. 
I would like to know if there is a specific method to find the number of solutions without computing them with the Chinese reminder theorem.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and consideration, this is the first question that I've done so I didn't really know how to start. I apologise for my mistakes, I'll try to get better in the future!

Comment: Hints until I can write an answer after I shower later, Fermat generalizes to Euler, equivalent residues,  factoring out, exponent rules, are all still useful.

Comment: This case is easy since there are no solutions $\bmod 3\,$ so none $\bmod 15\ \ \ $

Comment: How do we know that there are no solutions though?

Comment: $\bmod 3\!:\ x\equiv 0,\pm1\, $ none of which are roots